# if else - A posição das chaves "{}" faz diferença no resultado?

Tags: r, if, else

Estou fazendo web scrapping de um site. E para isso preciso verificar se um `data.frame` existe ou não.

Além de não estar funcionando, percebo que tenho resultados diferentes mudando apenas a posição das chaves `{}`

Exemplo 1:

```r
   if(exists(carteiras_i)==T) {
      if (nrow(carteiras)==0){
      carteiras <- carteiras_i
      } else {
      carteiras <- carteiras %>% rbind(carteiras_i); rm(carteiras_i)
      }
   } else (exists(carteiras_i)==F){
      print("Faz nada")
      }


#> Erro: '{' inesperado in:
#> "      }
#>   } else (exists(carteiras_i)==F){"
#> >       print("Faz nada")
#> [1] "Faz nada"
#> >       }
#> Erro: '}' inesperado in "      }"
#> > }
#> Erro: '}' inesperado in "}"
```

Exemplo 2

```r
   if(exists(carteiras_i)==T) {
      if (nrow(carteiras)==0){
      carteiras <- carteiras_i
      } else {
      carteiras <- carteiras %>% rbind(carteiras_i); rm(carteiras_i)
      }
   } else (exists(carteiras_i)==F){print("Faz nada")}




#> Erro: '{' inesperado in:
#> "      }
#>    } else (exists(carteiras_i)==F){"
#> > }
#> Erro: '}' inesperado in "}"
```

O que estou errando? Por que essa diferença só de mudar a chave?

Comment: Tente `else if (!exists(carteiras_i))` ou `else if (isFALSE(exists(carteiras_i)))`. Não compare uma condição ou função com um valor lógico com `F/T`, o valor da condição ou função **já é lógico**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não se coloca uma condição para o else, imagino que ali no final vc deveria colocar um

> else if (exists(carteiras_i)==F) {}

no lugar do seu

> else (exists(carteiras_i)==F)